# How to detect start of raw-rgb video frame?

Tags: python, video, rgb, gstreamer

I have raw-rgb video coming from PAL 50i camera. How can I detect the start of frame, just like I would detect the keyframe of h264 video, in gstreamer? I would like to do that for indexing/cutting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If this really is raw rgb video, there is no (realistic) way to detect the start of the frame. I would assume your video would come as whole frames, so one buffer == one frame, and hence no need for such detection.